# i missed part of the code that was making the error. curly brackets missmatched

Tags: javascript, error-handling, curly-braces

i missed the first part of the code that was involved

```
router.hooks({
  before: (done, params) => {
    const page =
      params && params.data && params.data.page
        ? capitalize(params.data.page)
        : "Home";

    if (page === 'Goexploring') {
      axios
      .get(process.env.NATIONAL_PARK_API_URL)
      .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      let hikingActivity = [];
      response.data.data[0].parks.map((parks) => {
        let output = '';
        hikingActivity.map((parks, index) => {
          output += `${parks.states}: ${parks.states[activities]}, `;
          return parks.states === 'TN';
        });
        console.log(hikingActivity);
        state.Goexploring.parks = hikingActivity;
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });
}
```

still saying it's miss matched. i left out a little bit of the code before sorry! wouldn't let me put it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of `}` and one `)` at the end, fixed:

```js
router.hooks({
  before: (done, params) => {
    const page =
      params && params.data && params.data.page
        ? capitalize(params.data.page)
        : "Home";

    if (page === "Goexploring") {
      axios.get(process.env.NATIONAL_PARK_API_URL).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        let hikingActivity = [];
        response.data.data[0].parks
          .map((parks) => {
            let output = "";
            hikingActivity.map((parks, index) => {
              output += `${parks.states}: ${parks.states[activities]}, `;
              return parks.states === "TN";
            });
            console.log(hikingActivity);
            state.Goexploring.parks = hikingActivity;
            done();
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: ok i see. even with the braces color pair extension it's still hard to get them to match sometimes. thank you!